# Refining inherited member to a specific subclass in Java

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a case where I think it would make sense to use inheritance, but I am not sure how best to execute it in Java. I understand that you cannot override a member in Java, but if you could, I would expect my case to work like this:

```
public class Y {...}

public class Ytype1 extends Y {...}

public class X {
    public List<Y> ys;
    ...
}

public class Xtype1 extends X {
    public List<Ytype1> ys;
}
```

Xtype1 is a type of X in which all of the members of ys are Ytype1. I would like any method in X that relies on ys to be able to run in Xtype1 using the ys in Xtype1, but I would also like to implement methods in Xtype1 that rely on all of the Y in ys being Ytype1.

I have considered overriding any method in X that would add to ys so that the methods would not work with Y that were not Ytype1, but I would prefer to avoid unnecessary typecasting.

Is there a proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for this:

```
public class Y {...}

public class Ytype1 extends Y {...}

public class X<T extends Y> {
    public List<T> ys;
    ...
}

public class Xtype1 extends X<Ytype1> {
    // super.ys is now List<Ytype1>
}
```

Comment: will X and Y be able to function fully on their own like this, or do I need to be using the subclasses?

Comment: @SudoNim You'll need to use `Xtype1` if you're adding an element to `ys`, because `X` doesn't know which type of `Y`s are valid input. But if you're just iterating or reading an element from `ys`, you can do it from `X` with a guarantee that you're getting `Y`s.

Comment: Ok, but I would also like to have instances of `X` where `ys` will accept any type of `Y`. Could I make and instance like `X<Y>`, or does `Y` not technically `extend Y`? I'm fairly unfamiliar with generics.

Comment: @SudoNim Yes, you could do that. Why don't you try?